# Store window size for sheet view controller

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

Is there any way to store window size in user defaults for view controller showed as a sheet? I'm using storyboard and segue with type sheet.

Comment: awkward question: _why...?_ but briefly, you could store such information in `NSUserDefaults` without any issue.

Comment: Sheet is resizable and has text view. it's not principal, just for usability.

Comment: and why can't you read the window's size in runtime? _why_ do you need to store it permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of my research

```
class SheetController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

  // MARK: - Interface Builder

  @IBInspectable var autosave: String?

  // MARK: - NSViewController

  override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    guard let window = self.view.window, let saveName = autosave else {
      return
    }

    window.delegate = self
    // restore window size
    window.setFrameUsingName(saveName)

  }

  // MARK: - NSWindowDelegate

  func windowDidEndLiveResize(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let saveName = autosave else {
      return
    }
    // save new window size
    self.view.window?.saveFrameUsingName(saveName)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. A bit annoying this isn't built-in automatically.